# Grinding on a new "Old Fashoined" bike

Tags: single-speed

I have an "Old Fashioned" Looking new bike, a cruiser with a single gear.  It pedals very smooth, but when I stop pedaling, I hear what can best be described as a grinding sound.  When I pedal again, it stops.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about the ratcheting sound you get from your freewheel?

Comment: No, it is not a ratcheting, (there are no gears).  It just sounds like a grinding, or a harsh rubbing sound.  When I pick the back wheel up off the ground, the tire still seems to turn freely for a while, but when it slows, it seems like I can see it being "grabbed" as it stops.

Comment: If you can coast, theres a freewheeling mechanism (freewheel/freehub) which has ratcheting in it. Are the brakes rubbing? Is the wheel aligned?

Comment: There are no hand brakes, just a coaster.  The Wheel seems to be aligned, I have not had that checked.  This has just started the last couple of times I have ridden it.

Comment: I agree with Batman's initial assessment.  The difference between the pedaling and not is the freewheeling mechanism.  Not pedaling also doesn't use your BB, but BBs that aren't moving rarely make a noise.  It sounds like perhaps your freewheel mechanism isn't disengaging all the way.  I'd get it checked soon as possible, partial engagement may eventually lead to none or full engagement.

Comment: The mechanism in a coaster brake hub includes a clutch for forward motion and a brake for stopping.  When the pedals are not moved the hub should engage neither.  It sounds like either the brake or clutch is being slightly engaged.  From my youth (a *long* time ago) I remember that some hubs were "just like that", but the problem could also be that you are unconsciously back-pedaling slightly, or there could be an actual malfunction.

Comment: (I'm remembering that a slight "swish-swish" sound from the hub while coasting was "normal" for some designs.)

Comment: Aside from making sure the reaction arm is correct and having the wheel in properly, theres nothing you can really do with a coaster brake IIRC.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the help!  I will get it looked at to see if the clutch is not engaging or disengaging correctly.    Steve

Comment: Coaster brakes can be rather easily disassembled and there are "clutch" parts available for common hubs. Requires a mechanic willing to get his hands dirty, though.

Comment: @Steve - this question is a year old now and has no accepted answer.  Could you please post an answer about what you've done, what the cause was, and how it was resolved ?   This is permitted and encouraged by SE because we'd rather have an answer than not.